# Remove a row in a pandas data frame if the data starts with a specific character

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with some text read in from a txt file the column names are `FEATURE` and `SENTENCES`.
Within the `FEATURE` col there is some text that starts with `'[NA]'`, e.g. `'[NA] not a feature'`.

How can I remove those rows from my data frame?

So far I have tried:

```
df[~df.FEATURE.str.contains("[NA]")]
```

But this did nothing, no errors either.

I also tried:

```
df.drop(df['FEATURE'].str.startswith('[NA]'))
```

Again, there were no errors, but this didn't work.

Comment: Can you create data sample for see your problem?

Comment: **The likely reason you're having difficulty is that the dtype of your columns is 'object', not 'string'.** Please use `pd.read_csv(..., dtype=...)` to fix the dtypes at read-time. Then show us `df.info()` to make sure the dtypes are what you assume they should be. Only string columns have a `.str` accessor to the string methods.

Comment: @smci, you may right, that's what i guess as well.. May be if OP can provide `df.dtypes` output at least.

Comment: i ran df.dtypes:  FEATURE     string
SENTENCE    string
dtype: object  it all appears to be a string but i get no errors but it just wont drop the line.

Answer (score 2):

Lets suppose you have DataFrame below:

```
>>> df
  FEATURE
0    this
1      is
2  string
3    [NA]
```

Then below simply should be sufficed ..

```
>>> df[~df['FEATURE'].str.startswith('[NA]')]
  FEATURE
0    this
1      is
2  string
```

other way in case data needed to formatted to string before operating on it..

```
df[~df['FEATURE'].astype(str).str.startswith('[NA]')]
```

OR using `str.contains` :

```
>>> df[df.FEATURE.str.contains('[NA]') == False]
  # df[df['FEATURE'].str.contains('[NA]') == False]
  FEATURE
0    this
1      is
2  string
```

OR

```
df[df.FEATURE.str[0].ne('[')]
```

Comment: If there is text `[NA] not a feature` why is necessary convert to string?

Comment: I'm thinking is there is only Value like `[NA]` where interpretation of the metacharacters getting expanded else simply `df[~df['FEATURE'].str.startswith('[NA]')]` will work.

Comment: Ya, only thinking about logic use `.astype`... But seems data are different like think OP

Answer (score 1):

IIUC use `regex=False` for not parsing string like regex:

```
df[~df.FEATURE.str.contains("[NA]", regex=False)]
```

Or escape special regex chars `[]`:

```
df[~df.FEATURE.str.contains("\[NA\]")]
```

Another problem should be trailing white spaces, then use:

```
df[~df['FEATURE'].str.strip().str.startswith('[NA]')]
```

Answer (score 0):

df['data'].str.startswith('[NA]') or df['data'].str.contains('[NA]') will both return a boolean (True/False) list. Drop doesnt work with booleans and in this case it is easiest using 'loc'

Here is one solution with some example data. Note that i add '==False' to get all the rows that DON'T have [NA]:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['feature','feature2', 'feature3', '[NA] not feature', '[NA] not feature2'], columns=['data'])

mask = df['data'].str.contains('[NA]')==False
df.loc[mask]
```

Comment: as per your representation of your DataFrame, it simply will work with `df[~df['data'].str.startswith('[NA]')]`  as it's expanding to regex underneath.

Answer (score 0):

The below simply code should work

```
df = df[~df['Date'].str.startswith('[NA]')]
```